# My fanatic badge disappeared

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

I noticed that my number of gold badges have reduced. Looking deeper, I found my fanatic badge has gone missing. I did visit the site 100 days everyday at some point of time and I've had this badge for more than 2 years now.

Please let me know why this happened? Is this part of a clean-up that SOF does which I might have missed or its just an accident?

My visit calendar is a proof for this. I have dates marked as visited consecutively from August 15 2010 to November 29 2010 which is more than a 100 days.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1977903/bragaadeesh)

Comment: This is an intervention, because we care about you

Comment: You took your tinfoil hat off, didn't you?

Comment: Here's something that I find strange, you've been a member of SO for 3 years, and yet your userID is 1977903.  I've been a member for shy of 2 years and mine is in the 600000s.  Did you have accounts merged at some point or anything?

Comment: @jonsca: I raised a request to moderator a week before to merge this http://stackoverflow.com/users/259869/bragaadeesh and http://stackoverflow.com/users/1977903/bragaadeesh which was not done. But I don't see this related to my badge disappearing.

Comment: Did you earn the badge under the 259869 account?  Even though your calendar still lists the dates in your consecutive streak, the badge itself may not have made the transition for some reason, and the script would have no reason to run again until you had 100 days with your combined account.  Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: @jonsca no. i never knew i even had that other account (259869) until few days before when i googled my name and i found that on top.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This was indeed due to the account merge.

The merge process was not migrating badges (as we have some automation around that already), however, this is disabled for some expensive queries, including the fanatic badge one.

Going forwards, such badges will be moved to the merge target. We have now also ran the queries backfilling such issues as your own.

Your fanatic badge is back.

Comment: Thank you very much ! As a follow up, did my account merge really happen ? Because, I still see two accounts http://stackoverflow.com/users/1977903/bragaadeesh and http://stackoverflow.com/users/259869/bragaadeesh