# Just lost my 'fanatic' badge and earned 35 points?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, badges, user-accounts

Not quite sure what's going on but after I created a Stack Exchange account (nat@natontesting.com) and tried to associate it to my http://nat-ritmeyer.myopenid.com OpenID account (that I've always used on SO, user ID: 275673), I seemed to have 're-earned' a ton of badges, gained 35 points (1623 now, 1588 yesterday), lost a bronze badge (not sure which one), lost my silver 'enthusiast' and gold 'fanatic' badges :(

Could ThePowersThatBe please fix this up and give me my gold badge back?

Comment: Similar issue perhaps? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165855/my-fanatic-badge-disappeared

Comment: I think the problem I'm having is a bit wider than that...

Comment: Given the last comment on the linked question, I think there might be a similar underlying scenario at play. Didn't vote to close this as a duplicate, but I think the link might be helpful to some of the powers that be. ;)

Comment: Ah, I see. But yeah, still not a dupe...

Comment: BTW, my new user ID appears to be: 2032500

Comment: Actually, those extra 35 points make sense as a few people have voted on answers I've given...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This was indeed due to the account merge.

The merge process was not migrating badges (as we have some automation around that already), however, this is disabled for some expensive queries, including the fanatic badge one.

Going forwards, such badges will be moved to the merge target. We have now also ran the queries backfilling such issues as your own.

Your fanatic badge is back:

[image: Fanatic Nat]

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar. Thanks for dealing with this! My fanatic badge isn't showing up yet, but I presume it's just a matter of time?

Comment: @NatRitmeyer - I've seen it for a few hours now. Are you looking at your profile page on SO and not MSO? (and don't forget to refresh).

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking at SO, and have refreshed. Thanks for your screenshot - when I saw that I went looking at my list of badges and can see it there. But, the badge count next to my username in the page header still shows a count of 2 rather than 3. Caching problem?

Comment: @NatRitmeyer - undoubtedly. It's always caching.

Comment: Be honest now. You just wanted to show off ;-)

Comment: @PeeHaa - I wish. With great power...

Comment: Didn't know you were on the team - congrats!

Comment: @AdamRackis - Thanks. Just started - I am sure a blog post will someday announce it ;)

Comment: The badges in the header now match the badges I actually have. That's one long lasting cache!!!

Comment: What about Unsung Hero? Did it suffer from the same problem? [see here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167523/152859)