# Where did my Unsung Hero badge go?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, merge-accounts, zero-score-badges

I have over 900 reputation and over a year of answering others programming questions on Stack Overflow, and I had a Unsung Hero gold badge about 2 weeks ago and I had just gotten it and within like a week it was gone and I got like 60 notifications of all of my badges being given to me (as if they were all taken away and given again) but the gold badge (maybe along with others) was not re-given. Can you lose a badge you earned? God bless!

Note: here is the page (just found it in my web history) of the badge I earned: https://stackoverflow.com/badges/226/unsung-hero?userid=773897

I may no longer meet the requirements for it, I don't know, but should that make a badge disappear, I feel like once you've earned something it should be yours to keep... just because I start answering more questions with different +1's or whatever makes me lose my only gold badge? In that case I should have just stopped answering questions hahahaha! :D

Here is a screenshot from my browser's (Safari's) history feature that shows me having 1 gold badge:

[image]

Comment: Which gold badge? It is *possible*, but normal badges are not taken away by any automated process.

Comment: (Besides not actually being able to see anything interesting in that picture, they have image editors that let you do things like... crop.)

Comment: I didn't add it to prove to you guys that I had one and I deserve it again, I would hope that SO backs everything up and can check this... I just added it to prove to myself that I'm not going crazy and I imagined the whole thing haha!

Comment: Did you have an account merge? I noticed that all your badges are currently awarded on February 9th. Account merges can reset all of your badges (which causes them to all be re-awarded), so if you no longer qualify for one, then you won't get it back.

Comment: Ah, I did merge because there was a glitch where when I set up my account with other stack exchange sites they were all shown as new accounts so I posted on here a while back about it and then I sent an eMail and then I relogged in with everything through Facebook and I lost my little gold pride.

Comment: I just don't feel I should be penalized for trying to use the site the way the admins intended (merged accounts), I'm sure they will see it the same way. Both accounts that were merged had the same username and eMail they just weren't linked for some reason, I think it was a glitch but I posted about it on Meta a while back.

Comment: I'm not aware of developers ever manually awarding badges. I'm afraid if the system thinks you no longer qualify, you're just going to have to try and qualify again.

Comment: It was a glitch, when my accounts were set up they were not connected for some reason (even though they all had the same eMail and usernames), when I had them connected I lost some of my badges. This shouldn't be happening.

Comment: I don't think the badge was manually awarded (although if it was that would be pretty awesome haha)

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw The comment was saying that they're not going to manually give it back to you. My point about the picture was that we can't read it: it's too small.

Comment: Why not though? If something in their system allowed a glitch that caused me to be penalized for no reason why shouldn't they revert the damage? I believe they are moral people, that seems the right thing to do.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Please use `@` replies. Why not? *If* they choose not to it's because it's not worth the effort: it's a gold badge. It's not *actual* gold; you cannot trade it in for anything interesting anywhere I'm aware of. I'm really not convinced "morality" comes in to the picture here.

Comment: @DaveNewton I believe they would want to provide all of their users a good user experience, I believe in compensation for glitches. That's where I'm bringing in the question of morality when it comes to re-awarding electronic items lost do to a glitch in your servers.

Comment: @All, in meta I would like to discuss things like what else can cause this glitch (So I stay clear of it next time) and who I should contact to have the glitch fixed and what not... if you would like to discuss what's fair and what you think should be done with my account please go here: http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/6050/morals-glitch-in-your-system-penalizes-user-undeservingly-do-you-compensate

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw: It's really *not* a glitch. Badges are reset upon an account merge because literally *everything* on your accounts needs to be recalculated to make sure that you don't have double votes on things, reputation you shouldn't have, etc. It sucks bu there's really not anything anyone can or will do.

Comment: @animuson but I wasn't merging two accounts I had on SO or anything.. I had signed on to OTHER stack exchange sites with my eMail and I did it so long ago I guess the accounts weren't links... I still only every had one stack-exchange account... If this is the case I'd rather have all of my other accounts deleted and return to the account I had on Stack-Exchange.

Comment: @animuson I could have never voted any of my owns posts up, as the accounts that I merged where on different sites completely.

Comment: They have definitely had problems with the multiple accounts thing, but it's probably a slim chance of you getting it back.  I would email them if I were you.

Comment: -1: If you could edit your post to write "Important details are in the comments below", then you could edit your post to *put the important details in your post!*

Comment: @LanceRoberts Thankyou for your helpful comment Lance, do you know the _best_ way for me to contact them?

Comment: The link at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @animuson this was confirmed to be a bug [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166489/152859) and even fixed for Fanatic, no reason why it shouldn't be fixed for Unsung Hero as well. Badges should not be taken back unless earned unrightfully in the first place.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Agreed!

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Yeah, this is a side-effect of the account merge. We're going to look at what we can do to fix this.

Comment: @AnnaLear thank you very much for your time, I understand  the purpose of the badge removal with an account merge if they user merged multiple accounts from the same site (because users could up vote their own responses) and that seems justified... I however only ever had 1 account on any given site so I appreciate you looking into it and hearing me out, thank you again for your time... God bless!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[The fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166489/152859) mentioned by [Sha Wiz Dow Ard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167541/140505) was only implemented for Fanatic and Enthusiast. I have now added UnsungHero, but unfortunately, unlike the other two, we have no way to recalculate it.

Going forward, Unsung Hero will get merged - I am looking at this specific case to see if there is any way for us to re-award it to Albert.

---

Update: We were able to confirm eligibility, thanks to some old backups, so the badge has been restored. However, this is not something that can be expected to work for everyone who lost the badge. Sorry.

As I said, going forward, this shouldn't happen anymore.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be pretty much "by design" but was recently addressed as a bug and fixed for other badge.

As Oded (newly recruited developer on the team) says [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166489/152859):

> The merge process was not migrating badges

He was talking about the [Fanatic](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/83/fanatic) badge but most likely [Unsung Hero](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/226/unsung-hero) falls under the same category.

He also says there:

> Going forwards, such badges will be moved to the merge target. We have now also ran the queries backfilling such issues as your own.

So it shouldn't happen anymore.

Comment: So great, its fixed but screw the OP? It really doesn't seem fair that he looses that badge entirely because of a flaw in the code - would it be possible to manually award the OP with the badge in this scenario?

Comment: I think it is possible, I left a comment to Oded let's see what he says.

Comment: Question, does this work like that still? If someone merges and they have the badge on one account and not the other what happens?

Comment: @meewoK as Oded said [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166489/152859): *Going forwards, such badges will be moved **to the merge target***. So suppose account A is merged into account B, if A had fanatic/unsung hero then after migration B will have it as well.

Answer (score 4):

It's unfortunate that the badge disappeared after your accounts merger. Unlike the Fanatic badge, for which a bug was identified [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165976/just-lost-my-fanatic-badge-and-earned-35-points/166489#166489), the Unsung badge is recalculated at the point of merger AFAIK.

I did a quick calculation based on your answers and you need four more zero-score accepted answers to qualify again; basically, you have either become a more "sung" hero or some questions have since switched their accepted answer.

Comment: Thankyou for the calculation! I just feel like recalculating makes since if you are merging two accounts on the same website because those accounts could have been used to up vote each other but I still only ever had one SO account so I don't think there should have been any recalculating at all, that's why it felt like a penalty to me for merging the accounts, at this point I would have rather not merged accounts, especially since I rarely ever use any of the other SE sites... I contacted the staff though and we'll see what happens!