# Do I lose the Tumbleweed badge if I delete the question?

Tags: support, badges, tumbleweed-badge

I earned the infamous [Tumbleweed](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/63/tumbleweed) badge for a question with almost no attention. Do I lose the badge if I delete the question?

Comment: See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work) under the `What can cause a badge to be lost/revoked/taken away after it is awarded?` section of the answer.

Comment: Have you tried it? Delete a question you got tumbleweed on. Then just un delete it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You do not lose any badges once they are awarded whether that may be because of deletion of a question or later downvotes.

There are a few exceptions to this general rule:

- Tag badges (ie [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), [html](/questions/tagged/html), etc. badges)
- A developer may remove a badge because it was gained via gaming the system
- A badge may inadvertently be removed when two accounts are merged

Comment: Exception is that a moderator can manually revoke a badge.  This is only done in suspicion of foul play.

Comment: Thank You! I have updated my answer.

Comment: Another exception is accounts merging. Until recently it caused certain badges to disappear, as merging did not transfer badges and it was only recently [fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167523/152859) for three badges but others might still be affected.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Thank You! I have updated my answer again :P

Answer (score 3):

Nope, once won it remains in your collection. This goes the same for badges like 'Unsung Hero' and 'Tenacious' which are awarded based on the moment of measurement, and whose criteria might not be met anymore afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

You don't lose the Tumbleweed badge, but you don't gain it the next time you have a question matching the requisites to get the Tumbleweed badge.

Comment: Tumbleweed is gained once thus this answer is irrelevant. You can't gain it again.

Answer (score 2):

**Not at all**, if you earn a badge once, it always persist in your profile **for forever**.
You can earn some badges many times, but most of them can be earned only *single time*.