# Something strange has happened with my badges

Tags: support, badges, achievements-dialog

Yesterday I decided to change the email for the newsletter for [PPCG](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com). However, not long after I had validated my email, the following had flooded my reputation inbox:

[image]

Now, note that I have been on Stack Overflow for three years and have earned all of these badges before.

Also, for some reason, it says I earned +3 rep in total yesterday, despite the fact that, in reality, I lost around 10.

Can anyone explain what on earth happened?

Comment: It isn't the first oddity with badge notifications: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283748/badge-notification-repeats

Comment: @rene not related. This one here is result of account merge, in which case all the badges are re-calculated in the merge target. The bug is the merge, and only a dev can look into it though.

Comment: @ShadowWizard yeah, I saw the differences, wasn't sure about the cause so that is why I brought it up.

Comment: @rene yeah... the merge is buggy in many aspects, always was, e.g. in the OP [network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/3244989/%CE%B2%CE%B5%CF%84%D1%A7-%CE%9B%D1%94%D2%AB%CE%B1%CE%B3?tab=accounts), SO appears with 0 questions and 0 answers, even though they do have posts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is result of account merge.

[This old account of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3576493/beta-decay) has been merged into [your current account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2736832/beta-decay).

When accounts are merged, all the badges are "re-calculated", and those you deserve are awarded again, and that is what you saw. This is confirmed by animuson in [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167523/where-did-my-unsung-hero-badge-go#comment492650_167523):

> Account merges can reset all of your badges (which causes them to all be re-awarded)

Comment: That sounds about right, thanks!

Comment: @Beta no problem, so I take it that the merge was not accidental? (In such case I'll remove the last paragraph.)

Comment: Well I can't see which account was merged with mine so I have no idea

Comment: @Beta you can still see it in [Google Cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:4pk69_rocI0J:stackoverflow.com/users/3576493/%25CE%25B2%25CE%25B5%25CF%2584%25D1%25A7-%25CE%259B%25D1%2594%25D2%25AB%25CE%25B1%25CE%25B3+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk).

Comment: I see. No that's not an accident